# Reading several nested .json files from a specific folder, into excel using python/pandas

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I want to read several nested json files located in a folder, into a excel file.
Since most of the .json files are different from each other(various nested levels in each file), it also means that some columns(values) in the excel file obviously needs to be NaN. I have no problem with reading a specific file with this code, but it will take a while to read 10 000 one by one.

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 

with open('file1.json','r') as f: #Here I want help, since i need to read 10 000 json files.
    data = json.loads(f.read())
multiple_level_data = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['data'], errors='ignore', meta =['total-count'], meta_prefix='config_params_', record_prefix='dbscan_')
multiple_level_data.to_excel('file1converted.xlsx', index=False)
```

However, how can I modify my python code to read all of the json files in the folder and not only file1.json?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `os.listdir()`:

```
import os
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 

for js in [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith('.json')]:
  with open(js,'r') as f: 
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    multiple_level_data = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['data'], errors='ignore', meta =['total-count'], meta_prefix='config_params_', record_prefix='dbscan_')
    multiple_level_data.to_excel(js+'converted.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you Wasif, this seemed to work perfectly, however, it created one excel file for each of the json files. 
Is it possible to instead of creating 10 000 excel files for each .json and instead merge this for loop into one excel file with 10 000 rows?

Answer (score 0):

The above solution from Wasif worked perfectly,
However I added this to get it into ONE excel file.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
     if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
         df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl'), ignore_index=True) 
df.to_excel("AllJsonFilesInOneExcel.xlsx")
```

Thank you.